# Где в памяти хранится информация о выполняемых методом действиях?

Tags: c#, .net, память

Локальные переменные метода, указатели кадра стека и тому подобная информация о методе хранится на стеке, в фрейме метода. А где хранится информация непосредственно о том, что делает метод? Допустим a + b, a и b это локальные переменные, мы их храним на стеке. А где и в каком виде хранится информация о том, что их нужно сложить? Где и в каком виде хранится семантика метода(что принимает, что возвращает). Искала по многим источникам, книгам, но однозначного и понятного ответа не нашла

Comment: Вас интересует то, как работает компьютер в принципе, или то, как работает конкретно .NET? В зависимости от этого ответ будет разный, потому что .NET добавляет дополнительную абстракцию в виде виртуальной машины и связанного с ней байткода (а также его JIT-компиляции на лету)

Comment: Ответить на конкретно этот вопрос легко - в памяти. Код в памяти, стек в памяти, куча тоде в памяти, всё находится в памяти. Когда процессор выполняет код, он всасывает себе в кеш участок памяти с инструкциями, поэтому чисто физически `a+b` на момент выполнения будет в кеше процессора. Семантика метода это высокоуровневое понятие, на уровне машинного кода его не существует. Конкретизируйте вопрос, с какой целью интересуетесь?

Comment: @aepot изучаю устройство .net и как платформа управляет памятью, хочется понять как именно все работает, подробно. Читала материал по ссылочным и значимым типам и задалась подобным вопросом при изучении стека. Пытаюсь понять какие компоненты программы и в каком виде хранятся в памяти.

Comment: Почитайте про Сборщик Мусора (Garbage Collector), узнаете практически всё про то как .NET работает с памятью.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, о чём вы спрашиваете, собственно и составляет тело программы, её исполняемый код. Программа на языке высокого уровня компилируется в исполняемый код и записывается в файл. Когда вы запускаете приложение, код из файла загружается в память и выполняется.

Для ответа приняты следующие допущения:

- поскольку в вопросе стоит метка `c#`, то упомянута именно компиляция;
- исполняемый код - это не обязательно машинный код, это может быть и код, исполняемый другим приложением (метка `.net`).

Операционная система выделяет приложению память под код в соответствии с информацией из файла и загружает в эту память код из файла. Память под данные запрашивается самим приложением после его запуска.

Код программы состоит из кода всех методов, которые в неё входят.

Память данных, как правило, состоит из участка статических данных (размер известен заранее из файла приложения), участка стека и участка кучи, который может дополнительно увеличиваться по запросу от приложения.

Семантика метода не хранится, она определяется самим кодом. То, что принимает метод, ложится на стек вызывающим методом. Вызываемый метод, соответственно, должен это прочитать. В завершение метода возращаемые данные тоже ложатся на стек самим этим методом и потом считываются вызывающим методом.